# Forcing Android Application to connect to wifi in marshmallow

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-6.0-marshmallow, wifimanager, captivenetwork

I am trying to forcefully move to wifi connection from Mobile data connection (3G/4G).

However this seems to work in Lollipop, however the callback for availability of network connection is not coming for marshmallow.

```
final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (networkType() != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
            request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);

            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                    if (SDK_INT >= LOLLIPOP && SDK_INT <= M) {
                        ConnectivityManager.setProcessDefaultNetwork(network);
                    } else if (SDK_INT > M) {
                        connectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is there something which I am missing?

Essentially I want to move to wifi so that I can connect to a Captive network if it is available. Moving from Mobile data to Wifi is the first step I am trying to do.